# Should selenium tests be kept in separate project

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I have a Java web app (Maven) where I have some Selenium tests.The testing framework is Junit 4.x.
I'm also using Jenkins for CI. Right now all my tests (integration + selenium) are kept under the src/test folder of the project.(classic maven structure)

Due to the fact that Jenkins cannot run selenium tests (it is not configured to do this - I'm running on a linux machine without a graphical interface and the solutions under this circumstances seems a little clumsily, but I was thinking to run a selenium server so that I can run all these tests on a windows slave machine ) I have to manually "remove from execution the selenium tests", otherwise I'll have a lot of failed tests.

What I want to accomplish is a scenario where:
1.Commit to SVN
2.Jenkins creates a build
3.Run the tests and if there is no problem here move to next step, otherwise,stop
4.Deploy the app to an app server
5.Run the selenium tests against that deployment as a post build script in Jenkins.

In order to have this running do I have to extract the selenium tests to other project ? (in order to avoid Jenkins running this tests along with the other integration/unit tests)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: There is only one question(In order to have this running do I have to extract the selenium tests to other project ?).  I just described the scenario that I want to use in order to be more clear for everyone what i`m looking for...

Answer (score 0):

As you are using **Maven** and you say `kept under the src/test folder of the project` sounds just **Perfecto**.

You havn't mentioned in your question why `Jenkins cannot run selenium tests (it is not configured to do this)`. As later in your question you have mentioned `Run the tests`, presumming you are using **TestNG** it's just one step configuration for **Jenkins** to execute **pom.xml** of **Maven** which will inturn call the ***testng.xml** as mentioned below :

- Ensure your **`Automated Test Suite`** executes properly as **`TestNG Suite`** and **`Maven Test`**.
- Start Jenkins and browse to `Manage Jenkins` -> `Configure System`
- Scroll Down to `JDK -> JDK installations` and ensure **`JAVA_HOME`** is set to **`C:\path\to\jdk1.8.0_144`**. Uncheck **`Install automatically`**
- Scroll Down further to `Maven -> Maven installations` and provide `Name` as  **`MAVEN_HOME`** & `MAVEN_HOME` as **`C:\path\to\apache-maven-3.3.3`**. Uncheck **`Install automatically`**
- Scroll Down to `JDK -> JDK installations` and ensure `Local Maven Repository` is set to `Default(~/.m2/repository)`.
- Apply & Save
- On **Jenkins Dashboard**, Create a `New Item` as `Maven project`.
- Scroll Down to `Build` section and provide **`Root POM`** as absolute path of the `pom.xml` e.g. **`C:\Users\<user_name>\LearnAutmation\maven.jenkins\pom.xml`**
- Set **`Goals and options`** to **`clean install`**
- The final step would be to move the **`testng.xml`** within **`\ProjectWorkSpace\src\main\resources\testng.xml`** and your **`pom.xml`** you have to mention the location of **`testng.xml`** as below :

```html
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.17</version>
 <configuration>
  <suiteXmlFiles>
   <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
  </suiteXmlFiles>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

- Build your project through **Jenkins**

---

As per your specific question `In order to have this running do I have to extract the selenium tests to other project ?` the answer is **No**.

### Solution :

- If you want to execute both the `Suites` **`Integration`** and **`Selenium`**, this setup is yours.
- If you want to execute either of the `Suites` seperately, divide the **`Integration`** and **`Selenium`** suites in different **`TestNG Groups`** and turn **ON** & **OFF** the execution of the **`TestNG Groups`**.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I have updated my post to answer to your questions. What I did not understood is how the selenium tests will be run as they have to be run against a "running" app, so I need somewhere after I run all the integration tests and the project is build to deploy to an app server, and only after that to run selenium tests. Is this correct? or am I missing something here?

Comment: @VideanuAdrian I don't observe any difference other than TestNG/JUnit for which the solution remains unchanged.

Comment: ok, but I still did not understood this: "What I did not understood is how the selenium tests will be run as they have to be run against a "running" app, so I need somewhere after I run all the integration tests and the project is build to deploy to an app server, and only after that to run selenium tests. Is this correct? or am I missing something here?"

Comment: Let the project to be build and deployed to an app server first. Then start the `Selenium` related `Tests`. `Selenium` will initiate a browser instance and execute your tests one by one.